# Timeout error after MySQL 8 upgrade on Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mysql-8.0

My Laravel 7 project uses MySQL 7 and we are trying to upgrade it to MySQL 8.

But after upgrading, we got a time-out issue when writing data on our most important table using the usual `Model::create([])` method and we really don't understand why.

Has anybody experienced such an error with Laravel when moving from MySQL 7 to MySQL 8?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: is this the first db request your app tries to make?

Comment: Can you check what's the value of `wait_timeout ` MySQL variable?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with MySQL? it's hitting an AblyRequestException, and Ably is for realtime messaging. What's line 139 of your controller?

Comment: seems `HTTP` timeout issue not `MySQL` timeout issue.

Comment: This is NOT the first DB request my app tries to make.

Comment: Line 139 is just trying to write a new entry on a table. This used to work absolutely fine with MySQL 7. That is why I am asking. It might be due to a bad configuration of MySQL 8.